# How can I reduce Estimated I/O and subtree cost in SQL Server Execution plan?

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan

I have a table with more than 1 million rows.
When I execute a simple SELECT query it takes about 17 seconds to retrieve the data.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

The execution plan gives the following info:

[image]

Furthermore, I have 5 non-clustered indexes and one clustered index.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Nothing will make that query more efficient - it selects every column of every row. A scan of the table is the best it can do.

Comment: And sending the results to the client is probably the most expensive part.

Comment: Obviously, if only certain columns are needed, selecting those columns would almost always be better than 'select *'

Comment: @SMor 
So what about plan cache?
Every time I execute the query it takes 17 seconds.

Comment: @AaronBertrand 
Nothing. I was checking why my db is slow in some situations and I encountered this case.

Comment: Like @SMor said, you can't do much on the query plan for such a simple query. Did you check wait statistics while the query is running?  Data pages must be read...  You could also look at internal fragmentation (free space in pages, is there a fill factor configured for your clustered index?).  If you pages are half empty, SQL Server must go through much more data pages it would need if there was more records packed per page.

Comment: @EricPrévost 
I haven't designed this db, and yes fill factor config is not the default. 
It has been configured on 90 percent.

Comment: @AaronBertrand oOo +1 for the "discard results" option in SSMS, that's a new one to me but probably very helpful. I usually select my results into a temp table when I want to eliminate return and render times while debugging performance, but obviously that can be a little misleading too. Commander, as everyone else has mentioned, this is likely just an *amount of data* problem. You're asking for 1 million rows of **all columns** to be **returned** and **rendered**. If you do the math on the amount of data it is, it'll likely show that 17s is a realistic runtime.

Comment: That is, most of the time is spent on the client side, your computer, rendering the results in SSMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see by using the view ;

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats WHERE session_id = @@spid
```

...before and after the execution of your query, that the waits are globally ASYNC_NETWORK_IO due to the fact that the engine must send the rows of the table from the RAM to the client application. The RAM is being accessed in few nanosecond, while the applications will use hundreds of milisecond to captue the data and place in into the object... and when this object has a graphical representation, this time is higher...

```
SELECT * 
INTO   #WAITS
FROM   sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats 
WHERE  session_id = @@spid;

SELECT * 
FROM   MyTable;

WITH T AS
(SELECT * 
 FROM   sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats 
 WHERE  session_id = @@spid)
SELECT T.wait_type, T.wait_time_ms - #WAITS.wait_time_ms AS WAITS_MS
FROM   T 
       JOIN #WAITS 
          ON T.wait_type = #WAITS.wait_type
WHERE  T.wait_time_ms > 0
ORDER  BY WAITS_MS;

--> DROP TABLE #WAITS
```

To see the cost of the graphical representation of data in SSMS, you can restart this test without viewing the data (Menue : Query / Query Options / Results / Grid / Discard results after execution...)